# navigate from static cells to different view controllers for each one

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've tried dozens of tutorials and example code to try to create an initial menu for my app that will allow navigation to different view controllers and back to the initial "menu" view controller.

I tried a regular view controller with buttons but got errors when I tried to implement segues from each to different view controllers.  I tried using a tableview controller wrapped in a navigation controller to start, but couldn't find an example that would allow me to have each cell segue to a different view controller and also navigate back to the "menu" controller.

It seems like a common type of navigation scenario so why can't I find any examples of how to accomplish this?  Does anyone have any suggestions or links to examples of something along these lines?

Comment: I tried the suggestion #1 from Abhishek before but got error when I ran it saying NSInternalInconsistencyException ... but did not get a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

To get this done you can use two approaches,

1. Using buttons and make button actions to navigate to another views.
2. Using TableView cells.

Here is the code for the tableView cell

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView          
{
   //Return the number of buttons you have
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       //You can use either switch cases to load the table view with the buttons you have.
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
      switch(indexPath.Section)
      {  
         Case 0:
         {
              //Code to push new controller
         }
      }
 }
```